# Create a dialogue

Tags: spacing, dialogue

I am a beginner in Latex. This is my problem.

I would like to type set a dialogue between three characters. I found the `dialogue` environment but it does not exactly cope with what I expect. [The following solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249912/write-a-command-easy-to-use-for-dialogues/532201?noredirect=1) almost do what I want :

```
    % arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \dia { o m } {%
    \begin{itemize}[%
        ,label=\IfNoValueTF {#1} {}{#1:}
        ,nosep % optional
        ,font=\color{red}
        ]
        \item #2
    \end{itemize}%  
    }

\begin{document}
\dia[First guy]{Hi, how are you?}
\dia[Second guy]{Fine and you?}
\dia[Guy with long hair]{My god, this dialogue is so boring.}
\dia[first guy]{Indeed, but have you heard that \blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[[image: Result[1]]
 But I would like to do some adjustments and therefore need to understand how it works.

1. I would like to enlarge the space between the character's name (`label`) and the speech.
2. what are the `o` and `m` in the `\declareDocumentCommand`
3. how the `\IfNoValueTF` works ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first point, just put some `labelsep` in your description of your `label` inside the `itemize` environment. For the other two questions, just read the `xparse` document: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/texlive-doc/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.pdf.

2. The `o` stands for optional argument and the `m` for mandatory argument. You don't need to put the name of who is talking but you must put a dialogue as an argument. Try yourself to erase `First guy` in your first dialogue or to quit the square brackets and do the same with the curly braces and see the output and the error given, respectively.
3. The `\IfNoValueTF` just checks if the optional argument was given or not and it will write what you put if some argument is given, if not, it writes some horizontal spacing.

Also, I loaded the `xcolor` package to avoid compiling errors. Change `black` to `red`, for example, and it will change your characters colours.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\dia{ o m }{%
    \begin{itemize}[%
        ,label=\IfNoValueTF {#1} {}{#1:}
        ,labelsep=8mm
        ,nosep % optional
        ,font=\color{black}
        ]
        \item #2
    \end{itemize}%  
    }

\begin{document}
\dia[First guy]{Hi, how are you?}
\dia[Second guy]{Fine and you?}
\dia[Guy with long hair]{My god, this dialogue is so boring.\\ %start a new line
Yeah! It's so boring.}
\dia[First guy]{Indeed, but have you heard that \blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Hope it works as you want!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your two answers. Do you know how can I add a paragraph inside an item ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want, but I updated my answer. Just put `\\ ` where you want to put a new paragraph `@JBOP`.

Comment: @SebastiánV.Romero thanks a lot. I mean can you seperate the speaker and their words to two lines?

Comment: I don't if I understand you correctly but substitute in the line 13 `\item #2` for `\item \phantom{}\\\phantom{}\\#2`. Hope it works as you want! :D `@PaulChen`

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to help!

1. To enlarge the space between the characters name and what they are saying, you should add `,labelsep=12.5mm` in the itemize-section. You can change the length to what you desire.
2. `o` means optional, `m` stands for mandatory. This means, that the first argument of the environment (`[label]`) is optional, the second, i.e. the input in `\dia{Hi! I'm the input!}` is not.
3. The `\IfNoValueTF` "executes" what you wrote behind it, if no `[label]` was found, e.g. when you use `\dia{Lemme say something}` and not `\dia[steve]{Lemme say something!}`. In this case, it will create a line.

If you have further questions, don't be afraid to ask!

Comment: can you seperate the speaker and their words to two lines?